# How to check bordering duplicates in an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, flood-fill

If I have an array that is made up of arrays that contain integers

```
arr[0] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1]    0
arr[1] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0]    1
arr[2] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0]    2

          0  1  2  3  4  5   6
```

And I, for example, want to check how many of the same integers border each other, both horizontally and vertically. For example, if I choose the coordinate (1, 2), which is a 0. I want it to output the number 8. Since there are 8 zeros that are continuous, where all border one another.
How would I be able to write a function that does exactly just that?

I have tried the following two functions in Python

```
print checkLoc(1, 2)

def checkLoc(x, y):
    amt = 0
    n = arr[y][x]
    checkPos(x, y, n)
    return amt

def checkPos(x, y, n):
    amt += 1
    if arr[y - 1][x] == n:
        checkPos(x, y - 1, n)
    if arr[y + 1][x] == n:
        checkPos(x, y + 1, n)
    if arr[y][x - 1] == n:
        checkPos(x - 1, y, n)
    if arr[y][x + 1] == n:
        checkPos(x + 1, y, n)
```

I would expect this to work but it does not. I have experimented with this for a bit and since I simply cannot figure it out I would appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh alright, thanks, didn't know. I originally put it there because I am using Processing to program Python in. Processing 3.3.6

Comment: I see, there was nothing about the question itself that has to do with Processing per se. The question itself seems pure Python. There is no problem with using the `processing` tag for a question that has to do with e.g. how `draw()` works in the Python mode.

Comment: Oh okay, fair enough. Sorry about that.

Comment: Isn't `arr[1][2]` equal to 1 rather than 0?

Comment: Originally saw it as (x, y), where x is horizontal and y is vertical. But no you are right.

Comment: You don't seem to guard against subscript out of range. It seems that you need to do something like a breadth-first-search from a given node. You can think of the coordinates as being points on an implicit graph, with the number at a node being something like a color. Algorithmically, you are trying to determine the size of the subgraph of same-colored nodes reachable from a given node.

Comment: It can be put like that, that is essentially what I am trying to do. In this case, though the nodes and their position are the arrays. The array arr represents the entire map, where arr[0] represents all the nodes in the first horizontal. Problem is, I recently realized that I had recently tried to achieve the same thing in a former project where I had to identify blobs of the color black in a sea of white and identify how many of these black dots there were in each of the blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your recursive approach you lacked a basis cases and failed to guard against subscript out of range. You also did nothing to prevent visiting the same position multiple times. The following implements the logic that you seemed to be trying to use, with the aid of a helping data structure to keep track of which positions were visited. Note that I made `arr` a local variable since I don't like using global variables without a good reason:

```
def checkPos(arr,visited,i,j,v):
    visited[i][j] = True
    if arr[i][j] != v:
        return 0
    else:
        count = 1 #current position
        if i > 0 and not visited[i-1][j]:
            count += checkPos(arr,visited,i-1,j,v)
        if i < len(arr)-1 and not visited[i+1][j]:
            count += checkPos(arr,visited,i+1,j,v)
        if j > 0 and not visited[i][j-1]:
            count += checkPos(arr,visited,i,j-1,v)
        if j < len(arr[0])-1 and not visited[i][j+1]:
            count += checkPos(arr,visited,i,j+1,v)
        return count

def checkLoc(arr, x, y):
    m = len(arr) # number of rows
    n = len(arr[0]) #number of columns
    visited = [[False]*n for _ in range(m)]
    v = arr[y][x] #value at the position
    return checkPos(arr, visited, y, x, v)

#test:

arr =[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0]]

counts = [[checkLoc(arr,j,i) for j in range(7)] for i in range(3)]
print('\n'.join(str(row) for row in counts))
```

The output is as expected:

```
[8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1]
[1, 8, 8, 8, 6, 2, 2]
[8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 2]
```

Comment: ah, I see. This guards against "subscript", and seems from your example to work. I'll try it out in my program, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do can be solved using a flood-fill algorithm. Consider your array.

```
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0]])
```

And a **flood-fill algorithm**, e.g.

```
def fillin(arr, x, y, new_value):
    """Graphically fills in `new_value` on location (x, y) replacing all
    adjacent values currently located there."""
    old_value = arr[y, x]
    n, m = arr.shape
    arr[y, x] = new_value
    if y > 0 and arr[y-1, x] == old_value:
        fillin(arr, x, y-1, new_value)
    if y < n-1 and arr[y+1, x] == old_value:
        fillin(arr, x, y+1, new_value)
    if x > 0 and arr[y, x-1] == old_value:
        fillin(arr, x-1, y, new_value)
    if x < m-1 and arr[y, x+1] == old_value:
        fillin(arr, x+1, y, new_value)
```

Then what this algorithm does is simply, e.g. **filling your adjacent zeros at (1, 2) with something else**

```
>>> fillin(arr, 1, 2, 2)
>>> arr
array([[ 2,  2,  1,  1,  1,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  2,  2,  2,  1, -1,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  1,  1, -1,  0]])
```

To make use of that **to solve your problem** code the cell you are investigating

```
(arr == arr[2, 1]).astype(int)
```

which gives you a 0-1 coding on your selection (here `arr[2, 1] == 0`) and then you substract the sum of that array before and after flood fill which gives you the number of iterative adjacent values for each position. Lets define **a method that checks one position** (that will also take care of not modifying the input `arr`)

```
def check(arr, x, y):
    arr_coded = (arr == arr[y, x]).astype(int)
    sum_before = arr_coded.sum()
    fillin(arr_coded, x, y, 0)
    return sum_before - arr_coded.sum()
```

In your case it will give

```
>>> check(arr, 1, 2)
8
```

Consider also to define a method to check the entire input array by

```
def check_all(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    return np.reshape([check(arr, x, y) for y in range(n) for x in range(m)], (n, m))
```

which will return a **matrix with the "same iterative adjecent value counts"**

```
>>> check_all(arr)
array([[8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1],
       [1, 8, 8, 8, 6, 2, 2],
       [8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 2]])
```